# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while using iterator

Tags: java, android

I have the following code to form a url, but some clients have reported exception at the for loop.
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)

```
    List<NameValuePair> requestParams = adRequest
            .createRequestParamsList(view.getContext());

    RequestTask currentTask = new RequestTask(this,
            view.getUserAgent(), view.getContext(), keyCode);

    try {
            currentTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,
                baseRequestUrl + Request.REQ_URI, requestParams);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

                String debugUrl = "";
                synchronized (this) {
                    debugUrl = baseRequestUrl + Request.REQ_URI + "?";
                    for (Iterator<NameValuePair> iterator = requestParams.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                        NameValuePair nvp = iterator.next();
                        debugUrl = debugUrl + nvp.getName() + "=" + nvp.getValue() + "&";
                    }
                    debugUrl = debugUrl.substring(0, debugUrl.length() - 1);
                }
```

requestParam is modified in RequestTask. why would it fail?

Comment: Do watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZOf3pOAM6A. Avoid Iterators

Comment: Im a little confused, as you arent modifying the requestParams object inside the iterator block.

Comment: Are you modifying `requestParams` in a different thread?

Comment: Yes, In the Async task called RequestTask in this case

Comment: If an `ArrayList` is modified while you are iterating over it with an `Iterator` you will get a `Concurrent ModificationException`.

Comment: The duplicate is irrelevant here because you are not modifying the `ArrayList` in the loop itself.

Comment: @PaulBoddington re-opened the question as the duplicate was irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

After your comments, I suspect you should synchronize on the `requestParams` object, not on `this`.

The async task does not have a reference to the object that is iterating, so they are not locking on the same object, which is virtually the same as not synchronizing at all.

Make sure both classes synchronize on the same reference of the same object!

PS: if both classes do a synchronized(this), they are effectively synchronizing on different object instances.

Answer (score 0):

When using an `Iterator` over an ordered set you must use `iterator.remove()` instead of `<? extends Collection>.remove()`. The latter yields a `ConcurrentModificationException`. If you are modifying `requestParams` in another thread and you must use the `Iterator` either have a field `private Iterator iter` in your class and provide a `getIterator()` method and perform the necessary null checks.